# find value from return API array in app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use app script and try to get value from return array by API, this is return array :

this is the full JSON:

```
   {data=[{first=[[10, 1], [14, 0], [13, 5]}]}
```

I use this code to get value but not woeking:

```
var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json = JSON.parse(request);
// this is the code to get value
const value= json.data.first.map(obj => [obj[0]]);
```

The error is : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: You're trying to map object before the data from API is loaded. That's why it's undefined. Read about async functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: If my assumption that the full json is `{data=[{first=[[10, 1], [14, 0], [13, 5]]}]}` (yours is lacking a single closing square bracket), then use `data[0]` before accessing `first`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full json's array you included is not properly closed.

modified it to this instead

`{data=[{first=[[10, 1], [14, 0], [13, 5]]}]}`

Upon doing that, this code should work.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var json = {data: [{first: [[10, 1], [14, 0], [13, 5]]}]};
  Logger.log(json)
  // access first array element of data
  var value= json.data[0].first.map(obj => [obj[0]]);
  Logger.log(value)
}
```

#### Using data[0]:

[image: output]

#### Using data:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Show your response

But maybe just

```
const [first] = json.data || []; // get 0 from array
const values = first.map(obj => [obj[0]])
```

Or maybe get object property

```
const { first } = json.data || {}; // get propetry first
const values = first.map(obj => [obj[0]])
```

Comment: Error `TypeError: first.map is not a function`

Comment: Please show result of console.log(json.data);

Comment: this is the full JSON `{data=[{first=[[10, 1], [14, 0], [13, 5]}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't look like JSON to me:

This works:

```
function myfunk() {
  const resp = '{"time":1632835594443, "first":[[10, 1], [14, 0.16306, 0], [13, 5]]}';
  const obj = JSON.parse(resp);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj.first));
}

8:26:36 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:26:37 AM  Info    [[10,1],[14,0.16306,0],[13,5]]
8:26:37 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: not working, Return null . this is the full JSON `{data=[{first=[[10, 1], [14, 0], [13, 5]}]}`

Comment: That's not JSON.  And my code is not returning anything.

Comment: I see the error oky I update that in another place can you checked that pleas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795163/get-value-from-api-json